# Find Minimum Timestamp From 2 Users POSTGRES

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, minimum

**This is my table_gamers:**

| game_id | user1 | user2 | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 890 | 123 | 2022-01-01 |
| 2 | 123 | 768 | 2022-02-09 |

**I need to find for each user:**

- The first user they played.
- Their first game ID.
- Their MIN timestamp (timestamp from their first game).

**This is what I need:**

| User | User They Played | Game ID | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 890 | 123 | 1 | 2022-01-01 |
| 123 | 890 | 1 | 2022-01-01 |
| 768 | 123 | 2 | 2022-02-09 |

**This is my query:**

```
SELECT user1 FROM table_gamers WHERE MIN(timestamp)
UNION ALL 
SELECT user1 FROM table_gamers WHERE MIN(timestamp)
```

How do I query each User's First Opponent? I am confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doing step by step by some with_clauses:
first get all matches user1-user2, user2-user1
second give some ids by ordering by timestamp
third get what you want:

```
with base_data as (
select game_id,user1,user2,timestamp from table_gamers
union all 
select game_id,user2,user1,timestamp from table_gamers
),
base_id as (
select
  row_number() over (order by base_data.timestamp) as id,
  row_number() over (PARTITION by base_data.user1 order by base_data.timestamp) as id_2,
  *
  from base_data
)
 
select * from base_id
where id_2 = 1 order by timestamp
```

retults in

```
id  id_2    game_id user1   user2   timestamp
2   1   1   123 890 2022-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
1   1   1   890 123 2022-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
4   1   2   768 123 2022-02-09T00:00:00.000Z
```

i hope that gives you the right idea

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9PrxioFeVaTmtVcYdteovj/0